# Serving files in src/main/resources using Java Jetty

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jetty

I am trying to create a simple Java Jetty/Jersey project with Maven and have successfully got Jersey to return content back to the client from the methods defined in Java classes. I believe that I have set up my Jetty server such that the files in `src/main/resources` can also be returned to the client through the use of `ServletContextHandler.setBaseResource` method in `WebServer.createServer`. However, when I navigate to the URL for one of these files, Jetty returns a 404 file not found error.

My understanding of the server setup is that when a request is made, the Jersey classes are checked for a matching path, if one is found then the content is returned, if there isn't a matching path then the base resources are searched and if a file matches the path it is returned.

My Jetty server class is located in `src/main/java/WebServer.java` and is as follows:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.ResourceCollection;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

public class WebServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = createServer();
        try {
            server.start();
            System.out.println("Server started");
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Server createServer() {
        Server server = new Server(9090);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/");
        Resource resources = createStaticResources();
        context.setBaseResource(resources);
        ServletHolder servlet = createServlet();
        context.addServlet(servlet, "/*");
        return server;
    }

    private static ResourceConfig createResourceConfig() {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.packages("Controllers");
        config.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        return config;
    }

    private static ServletHolder createServlet() {
        ResourceConfig config = createResourceConfig();
        ServletContainer container = new ServletContainer(config);
        ServletHolder servlet = new ServletHolder(container);
        return servlet;
    }

    private static Resource createStaticResources() {
        String[] locations = new String[] {
            "src/main/resources/"
        };
        Resource resources = new ResourceCollection(locations);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

My Jersey handler class is located in `src/main/java/Controllers/Main.java` and is as follows:

```
package Controllers;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/")
public class Main {
    
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/page1")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String page1() {
        return "Page 1";
    }
}
```

Where have I misunderstood the Jetty server setup that is resulting in these 404 errors?

Comment: *config.packages("Controllers");* I don't know this API but it looks like that's going to make 'Controllers' (incidentally package names should be all lower case in Java) the place where it's going to look for resources. You've got them in '/' and you don't want to be mixing them in with your classes. You might *try* creating src/main/resources/resources and put them in the 'package' called 'resources'. Your code would then be  `config.packages("resources");` Worth a try ;) **OR** try creating an *actual* package /src/main/java/resources and put them in there. I'd be surprised if both fail

Comment: The `src` directory isn't there at runtime. You're trying to serve from the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

The `ServletContextHandler` wont serve static files on its own you need to add a `DefaultServlet` to that. Or configure an additional `ResourceHandler`.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-10/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/DefaultServlet.html

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-10/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ResourceHandler.html